Given points $A(2, 4)$ and $B(-3,-8)$, counting points $C$ such that $\angle ACB$ is right and $\triangle ABC$ has a given area

Let $A(2, 4)$, $B(-3,-8)$, and $C(x,y)$ be three points such that $\angle ACB$ is a right angle and the area of $\triangle ABC$ is $41/2$ units. The number of such points $C$ is:
(a) $0\quad$ (b) $2\quad$ (c) $4\quad$ (d) Infinite

Here is my attempt: By using the determinant which gives the triangle's area, I got an equation of $(x,y)$ is $12x-5y=45$. And by the distance formula for a right angle area $\frac12\text{base}\times\text{height}$, I found a fourth-degree equation:
$$ (x+3)^2+(y+8)^2(x-2)^2+(y-4)^2=41$$
How go solve from here?
I am preparing for a teaching exam after my poorly graduation. So we have a telegram group where we get lots of different problems related to different topics. So this problem is shared by a user maybe a TGT book from which they are preparing.

Please provide the 4th degree eqn you found out

@Gwen it is too much big because (x+3)^2+(y+8)^2(x-2)^2+(y-4)^2=41

Hint: Thales' theorem

@ChrisLewis brilliant idea. I used it and by distance formula i got two variable equation and now we have 2 equation 2 variable and i got 1 value

One thing I don't understand: the only important thing is the distance between the points $A$ and $B$ (which is $13$) and the only result you need is the amount of $C$ points. Then why have such weird coordinates? Just put $A$ on the point $(0,0)$ and $B$ on the point $(13,0)$. That will make calculations much easier :-)

@Dominique can you explain more how this make calculation easy? Because if I draw the triangle with C at 90° and use the distance formula then it will be same issue no? CA^2+CB^2=AB^2,(x^2+y^2)+(x-3)^2+y^2=169

This is a conceptual answer. $AB$ is the hypotenuse. Let $AB$ be the diameter of a circle, and $C$ an arbitrary point on the circumference. Maximum area of the triangle that it can subtend on $C$ will be $$\frac{1}{4} (AB)^2=\frac{169}{4}(=42.25)>\frac{41}{2}>0$$

Using the fact that the diameter always subtends an angle of $90°$ on the circumference, we will get $2$ points satisfying our condition in every semicircle, and this $4$ points in the entire circle. Thus there are four possible positions of $C$


Could you explain how are you getting 2 points in semicircle i didn't understand this part

@CiupTitu I guess the gif I made will help you :)

This is awesome explaination. is this what they said thales theorem? @cheris

@CiupTitu Yes, this is one of his theorems.

How did you make the gif? I’m guessing it is a bunch of stills from geogebra, but how the gif itself?

Could you tell me how you got ab^2/4? Is this fourth part of square?

@CiupTitu It's the area formula, $\frac 12 × h × b$

@Sahaj here you go

thanks @Gwen :)

I am sorry Guys. All the credit goes to @nawalalluarjun. He introduced this extraordinary awesome site to me

@CiupTitu welcome my friend

Why question is closed? This is so ridiculous

@CiupTitu you can edit your question to add why the problem was important to you, where did you find it...etc. You/me can reopen it then

@Gwen I am preparing for a teaching exam after my poorly graduation. So we have a telegram group where we get lots of different problems related to different topics. So this problem is shared by a user maybe a TGT book from which they are preparing.

@CiupTitu add this to your post

I like the geometrical solution that is here.
If you want an algebraic solution....
Let $C = (x,y)$
$\angle ACB$ is a right angle.
$(C-A)\cdot(C-B)= 0\\
(x-2)(x+3) + (y-4)(y+8) = 0\\
x^2 + x - 6 + y^2 + 4y - 32 = 0\\
(x+\frac 12)^2 + (y+2)^2 = \left(\frac {13}{2}\right)^2$
This is the circle in the algebraic solution.
Line AB: $12 x - 5y -4=0$
We need a line some distance away from $AB$ such that the area is correct.
$\frac 12 bh = \frac {41}{2}$
$b$ is the length of the line segment $AB$
$b^2 = (2+3)^2 + (4+8)^2 = 169\\
b = 13\\
h = \frac {41}{13}$
Plugging $x,y$ from C above into the distance formula
$\frac {|12x-5y+4|}{\sqrt {12^2+5^2}} = \frac {41}{13}\\
12x - 5y + 4 = \pm 41$
We now have two lines and a circle.
If both lines are tangent to the circle, we have two solutions.
If each line intersects the circle we have 4 solutions.
If the lines do not interact with the circle we have no solutions.
